# browserify in debug mode give coffee files in the chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, browserify

```
function watchAndBuild(options) {
    var bundler = browserify({
        // Required watchify args
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true,
        // Browserify Options
        entries: ['./coffee/' + options.src ],
        extensions: ['.coffee'],
        transform: ['coffeeify'],
        debug: true
    });
    var bundle = function() {
        return bundler
            .bundle()
            .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify error'))
            .pipe(source( options.filename + 'app.js'))
            .pipe(rename(options.filename + '.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/assets/javascripts/build/' + options.dest));
    };
    bundler = watchify(bundler);
    bundler.on('update', bundle);
    bundler.on('update', console.log.bind(console));
    return bundle();
}
```

Im using watchify and browserify as shown above. This is working fine tracking my changes and rebuilding properly. The only problem is it is generating coffee sourcemaps i.e it is showing coffee files in the chrome devtools. I want javascript sourcemaps.

**Edit:**
Why I need js sourcemaps: It is hard to debug coffee files in devtools, like adding a breakpoint, step over, step into etc.

One way to solve this i.e to have js files instead of coffee files is to compile all coffee into js and then use browserify to combine js. This method is little unoptimised. In order to watch the files Ill have to watch coffee and also the compiled js

Is there a direct way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want source maps that don't show the source code? I think simply commenting out the `.pipe(source...` line should remove the source maps and let you see the generated JS - which should be sufficient as you aren't minifying, obfuscating or uglifying the code

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Please see the edits